# How can a Report to Display State Abbreviations?

Tags: civireport, reports

The report "Membership Details" at civicrm/report/instance/23 shows "State/Province" in the results, but we want to see the State abbreviation instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can either user [alterReportVar](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/) hook to alter the result or add a new column via the same hook to display State Abbreviation.

Answer (score 2):

A no-coding solution is to rebuild the report in SearchKit.

You need to explicitly join to the State/Provinces, but once you do, you can add a display, then use the "Rewrite" on the state/province, changing it to abbreviation with this token: `[Address_StateProvince_state_province_id_01.abbreviation]`. Below the screenshots is an export of my query and display, you can import it to use as an example.

Attached are screenshots showing this in use.

#### My Query Configuration

[image]

#### My Display Configuration

[image]

```
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "example_abbreviation",
          "label": "example abbreviation",
          "form_values": null,
          "mapping_id": null,
          "search_custom_id": null,
          "api_entity": "Address",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "id",
              "Address_StateProvince_state_province_id_01.name"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [],
            "groupBy": [],
            "join": [
              [
                "StateProvince AS Address_StateProvince_state_province_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "state_province_id",
                  "=",
                  "Address_StateProvince_state_province_id_01.id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          },
          "expires_date": null,
          "description": null
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    "SearchDisplay",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Addresses_Table_1",
          "label": "Addresses Table 1",
          "saved_search_id.name": "example_abbreviation",
          "type": "table",
          "settings": {
            "description": null,
            "sort": [],
            "limit": 50,
            "pager": [],
            "placeholder": 5,
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "id",
                "dataType": "Integer",
                "label": "Address ID",
                "sortable": true
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "Address_StateProvince_state_province_id_01.name",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Address State/Province: State",
                "sortable": true,
                "rewrite": "[Address_StateProvince_state_province_id_01.abbreviation]"
              }
            ],
            "actions": true,
            "classes": [
              "table",
              "table-striped"
            ]
          },
          "acl_bypass": false
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name",
        "saved_search_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [civicrm_alterReportVar](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/) hook, this can be coded fairly easily. Here is very simple code (for WordPress) to adjust the state from the full name to the abbreviation, using the CiviCRM API:

```
// Implements hook_alterReportVar
add_filter( 'civicrm_alterReportVar', 'DNS_alterReportVar_callback', 10, 4 );
function DNS_alterReportVar_callback($varType, &$var, $reportForm) {
  if ('rows' == $varType && 'Detail' == $reportForm->getname()) {
    foreach($var as $k => $row) {
       $stateProvinces = \Civi\Api4\StateProvince::get()
         ->addSelect('abbreviation')
         ->addWhere('name', '=', $row['civicrm_address_address_state_province_id'])
         ->execute();
       $var[$k]['civicrm_address_address_state_province_id'] = $stateProvinces[0]['abbreviation'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to write Civi code, it's generally preferable to put it in a CMS-agnostic Civi extension rather than making it specific to WP - partly because it is more discoverable showing in the list of installed Civi extensions. `civix` creates all the boilerplate for you.